# HAdoop Pipes: get the Value of a Counter variable

Tags: hadoop, pipe

I am using Hadoop Pipes. I have been able to register a counter and increment its value. But I am unable to find any method to access/read the value of the counter. Is there a way to do it ? Please help!!

--
Thanks
tan